# Finding Linearly Independent Monomials on a Plane

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm seeking help to prove a procedure I've been using (successfully) to find a basis among a set of monomials on a plane.

Let $M$ be the set of monomials on $\mathbb{R}^d$ of degree not greater than $k\in\mathbb{N}$.

Just to be clear by "monomial" here is meant $(x_1,...,x_d) \rightarrow {x_1}^{k_1}\cdot \ldots \cdot {x_d}^{k_d}$ where $\sum_i k_i \le k$.

On the whole of $\mathbb{R}^d$, these monomials are easily shown to be linearly independent.  However, if the monomials are restricted to a plane of degree $d-1$, then they are dependent, so we need to remove some to form a basis.

I've got a simple procedure to do this, which however needs proof (which is the question being posed).

The procedure is this:  choose a coordinate which can be expressed as a linear combination of the others on the plane. Then just remove from the set all of the monomials which involve a non-zero power of that "dependent" variable.  It's clear that these monomials do span the same space, just by substitution of the expression for the dependent variable as a l.c. of the others in place of the dependent variable in any monomial of the original full set - that willl yield a polynomial free of the "dependent" variable and satisfying the same degree constraint.

The question is how to show that the reduced set of monomials is in fact linearly independent?

Answer (score 0):

By exactly the same argument by which you see that "On the whole of ${\mathbb R}^d$, these monomials are easily shown to be linearly independent".

It's probably easiest to reduce the problem to ${\mathbb R}^{d-1}$. The monomials in $x_1, \dots, x_{d-1}$ are linearly independent and the vector space they span is isomorphic to your vector space of restricted monomials. Assuming, without loss of generality, that it is $x_d$ that you wrote as a linear combination of the others, the monomials are even the same as formal expressions.

Comment: The part which is still not clear to me is that the space spanned by $x_1,...,x_{d-1}$ on $R^{d-1}$ is isomorphic to the space of monomials of the same expression on the plane. Say T is that candidate isomorphism, from standard $R^{d-1}$ monomials to the planar ones, taking a standard $R^{d-1}$ monomial to the one with the same expression on the plane.  I see that it is onto the target space, but how to see that it's injective?

Comment: You somehow need to use that if two monomials agree on your plane $P$, then they also agree on ${\mathbb R}^{d-1}$. For this, write down explicitly the isomorphism between the monomials in ${\mathbb R}^d$ restricted to $P$ and the monomials in ${\mathbb R}^{d-1}$ not in terms of their representation as formal expressions, but as functions. (The key is: composition with the projection $P \to {\mathbb R}^{d-1}$)